# Looking for an electronic copy of Huber's Bewertungsspektrum und rigide Geometrie

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, p-adic, paper-request

Lately I've been trying (and have failed) to find an electronic copy of Huber's *Bewertungsspektrum und rigide Geometrie*, which (from what I understand) is the original reference developing the basics of the theory of adic spaces. Is it available online somewhere?

Comment: If nothing else, you can try writing to [Roland Huber](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~huber/).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda That's a good idea! I'll send Huber an email. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An electronic copy of "*Bewertungsspektrum und rigide Geometrie*" is available [from Wuppertal University](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~huber/preprints/Bewertungsspektrum%20und%20Rigide%20Geometrie.pdf).

*[year-old post, bumped to the front page by a spammer, answered for the record]*

Comment: I want to record Huber's generosity in how this electronic version came to be: From what I remember, I contacted Huber around the time I asked this question, asking if he had a copy of his *Bewertungsspektrum*; he replied saying that he didn't have an electronic copy, but (very generously) he offered to mail me a physical one. I then scanned it and sent the electronic version back to him, and it seems he uploaded it to his webpage a couple months later =)